# How to match a string from the searched text highlight the text in the html in angular4

Tags: angular

how to match a string from the searched text and the array of objects and highlight the text in the HTML in angular4

```
 I am using pipe for this.
 `@Pipe({ name: 'researchfilter' })


export class researchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
searchtext: any;

constructor(private searchTermUpdataionService:searchTermUpdataionService)
{
this.searchTermUpdataionService.getupdatesearchfilter().subscribe((Object: 
any) => {

  this.searchtext = Object.searchFilter.searchTerm

 });
}
transform(items: any): String[] {
if (!this.searchtext) {
  return items;
}
console.log("items",items);
if(items!= null && this.searchtext !=  null){
let newitem = items.toLowerCase()
var pattern = this.searchtext.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, 
"\\$&");
pattern = pattern.split(' ').filter((t) => {
  return t.length > 0;
}).join('|');
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');
return this.searchtext ? newitem.replace(pattern, (match) => `<span 
class="highlight">${match}</span>`) : newitem;
}`
```

And this is my HTML

```
  <p  class="mdl-color-text--800" style="font-weight: bold ;color: #212121" 
  [innerHTML]="sources?(sources[0].name | researchfilter : 
  searchFilter):''"></p>
```

I am getting the name in items and I am getting the search string in 
  this.search text, but cant able to highlight the string in HTML

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Comment: @ Dima Kozhevin i have added my code sample above , i have used pipes for this , i am getting the text and search string ,but cant able to highlight in HTML,can you please check and tell